# Node.js File to Angular file upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to figure out how to connect a Node.js FileSystem to an angular file upload directive.

I get the file from Node using:

```
var file = brackets.test.FileSystem.getFileForPath('/Users/me/Desktop/new-year-2015.jpg')
```

The resultant object looks like:

```
File {_isFile: true, _name: "new-year-2015.jpg", _parentPath: "/Users/me/Desktop/", _path: "/Users/me/Desktop/new-year-2015.jpg", _fileSystem: FileSystem…}_fileSystem: FileSystem_id: 89_impl: (...)_isFile: true_name: "new-year-2015.jpg"_parentPath: "/Users/me/Desktop/"_path: "/Users/me/Desktop/new-year-2015.jpg"
```

I'm trying to upload this object to server with:

```
$upload.upload({
                    url: 'https://localhost/upload',
                    file: file,
                    fileName: getFilenameFromPath(file),
                   });
```

On server the file is received as null.

How can I use a node.js file object in an angular file upload?

Comment: You should probably also show your server-side code.

Comment: Server side node.js or server side the destination (which is PHP)?